# UINavigationControllerでWebViewのバックをハンドルする事は出来ますか？

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

webviewを含んだviewControllerをNavigationControllerにpushした後、
webview内での画面遷移がスタックされている場合、バックボタンはwebview内でバック、無くなれば元の画面にバックとしたいです

Answer (score 1):

簡単な方法では、ボタンを非表示にし、自作する方法があります。

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.co.jp/"]]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    //非表示
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
    UIBarButtonItem * back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(didBackButtonTap:)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:back];
}

-(void)didBackButtonTap:(UIBarButtonItem *)item
{
    if (webView.canGoBack) {
        [webView goBack];
    }else{
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

そのままで使うには、backボタンをフックする必要があります。
方法は、本家に参考になる質問がありました。

[UINavigationController: How to cancel the back button event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19133451)